# How to get rid of hovering circular notification shortcut in CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Ever since I installed CyanogenMod, there has been this hovering blue circular notification on top of every application. I don't know what its called so I really can't find a way to disable this. Can anyone help me identify what it is and how to get rid of it? Attached is a screenshot.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size image</sup>

Comment: That looks a lot like the [HALO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5WljHcOyXs) feature from Paranoid Android, which isn't typically a part of CM. Is this an official CyanogenMod build?

Comment: Have you tried to "slide" that "blue circle" from the border toward the center of the screen? It might open a quick-access menu. But as eldarerathis wrote, I'm not aware that CM ships with such a thing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @eldarerathis the link to the video helped me get rid of it.

To get rid of it, I had to DOUBLE tap the "halo" and move to the X area just as you would when getting rid of apps from the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, Accessibility, Motor, and Cognition, and turn off Touch Assistant.
That should take care of the little blue thing for you.